# Changing values of a matrix randomly (Python)

Tags: python, matrix, random

The matrix is 15x15, and I need to randomly add values to it. Either if a person is dead or alive. For this I typed:

```
class Individuo:
def __init__(self, vivo, representacion):
    self.vivo = False
    self.representacion = representacion
p_vivo = Individuo(True, "*")
p_muerto = Individuo(False, "#")
```

Then, I tried to do this to insert it randomly into the matrix:

```
  for sublistas in matriz:
     for espacios in matriz:
        ran = random.choices(p_vivo, p_muerto)
           matriz.append(ran)
```

I get an error on:

```
ran = random.choices(p_vivo, p_muerto)
```

How can I add these values to a matrix randomly?

Answer (score 0):

First, the function is [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/random.html#random.choice) **not** `random.choices`.

Second, `random.choice` takes a sequence (like a list or a string)  as it's first argument.  You have passed two separate arguments.

What you really want to do is say `random.choice([p_vivo, p_muerto])`.